# Need sections to appear after each row in UITableView using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView where there are three sections (0, 1, 2).  Section 0 can have multiple cells, whereas sections 1, and 2 have only a single unique cell.  What I am unable to figure out, is how to have sections 1, and 2, and there respective cells appear after each cell of section 0.  In other words, I want my UITableView to have the following architecture:

```
Section 0
row 0
Section 1
row 0
Section 2
row 0
Section 0
row 1
Section 1
row 0
Section 2
row 0
Section 0
row 2
Section 1
row 0
Section 2
row 0
...
and so on.
```

At the moment, unfortunately I have the following architecture instead:

```
Section 0
row 0
row 1
row 2
...
Section 1
row 0
Section 2
row 0
```

I haven't provided any code because I am not sure what is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very easy if you understand what rows and sections are.

In the `UITableViewDataSource` methods, specify:

1. One row per section (regardless of which section), i.e.

   ```
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection:Int) -> Int
   { 
       return 1 // All sections have one row
   }
   ```
2. One section per entry in your data model/array/etc.

   ```
   func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int
   { 
       return myArray.count // One section per item(row)
   }
   ```

   ...Then, when configuring each cell, look at the section of te index path passed to `tableView(_: cellForRowAtIndexPath:)`:

   ```
   let item = mayArray[indexPath.section]
   // configure cell using item, and return it
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You want to your tableview's first section to have multiple sections and rest sections to have 1 cell each. First hook up your tableview to IBOutlet in code . Then in your class declaration have delegate and datasource like

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {
```

then in viewDidLoad

```
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self
```

after that implement the datasource functions

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection:Int) -> Int
{ 
if section == 0{
return 3 // your value to return rows for 1st section
}else{
return 1 // rest for all sections
}
}
```

and get as many as sections as you want with

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int
{ 
return value // your value to return for number of sections
}
```